# LEGO Train - what size cork track bed

Tags: trains

What size model train cork track bed should I buy to fit under a standard LEGO train track?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LEGO trains typically use a 2x8 plate for their sleepers (ties), with a stud protruding from each rail, giving a 40mm centreline gauge for the track and 64mm width for the sleepers - this is 5.5mm wider than O-Gauge - so might be a little hard to find off the shelf.

Lots more detail can be found on [L-Gauge.org](http://l-gauge.org/wiki/index.php?title=Track_Geometry#LEGO.C2.AE_Brand_Track).